# JPA: How do I get a scalar result of type Long-- not BigNumber-- from Oracle NUMBER?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

The default mapping from an Oracle NUMBER value is into BigNumber... How can I get a scalar result query to return a Long instead?

Answer (score 0):

relent ye who enter here; i ended up just creating a shill entity with a field of type Long to fill.  apparently Oracle & hibernate hate ye all and will not give you anything but BigNumbers.

Comment: (edited to remove unnecessary tone that was attracting flags)